# Css animation - Show/Hide logo with an handwriting svg effect

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

I am simulating an handwriting animation of an `svg`, which is activated when the user holds the mouse down. According this [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060838/svg-handwriting-animation-without-using-stroke-properties), to create this effect I am overlapping the logo with an svg which is a `stroke` line of the logo itself, and I am turning the color to `transparent` to reveal it.

The logo should be revealed on `mousedown` and get hidden again on `mouseup` through the following script:

```
var logoElements = document.querySelectorAll('#first svg *');
var down = false;

function checkMousePosition() {
  for (i = 0; i < logoElements.length; i++) {
    if (down == true) {
      console.log(logoElements[i].getTotalLength());
      logoElements[i].classList.add("animation-forward");
      logoElements[i].classList.remove("animation-backward");
    } else {
      logoElements[i].classList.remove("animation-forward");
      logoElements[i].classList.add("animation-backward");
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://codepen.io/Zack_90/pen/aBKEwe) with the complete code. It seems to work but at the moment I am having the following issues:

- `console.log(logoElements[i].getTotalLength());` throws an error saying it is not a function.
- The logo should be hidden at the beginning and get revealed on click, not viceversa and the responsivness is slow.

Do you have an idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Uhh, where exactly is `getTotalLength` function ? Moreover you are getting the length of an item in an array ? It should be `logoElements.length` not `logoElements[i].length`

Comment: It is included in the svg path elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement

Comment: It is included, but you haven't checked how widely it is supported. The logo is hidden for me on page load and revealed on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `getTotalLength` works only width path, so you have to write your own function to get length of other elements or translate them into path (should be simple as they are just lines).

Then use this js:

```
var logoElements = document.querySelectorAll('#first svg path');
for (i = 0; i < logoElements.length; i++) {
    logoElements[i].style["strokeDasharray"] = logoElements[i].getTotalLength();
    logoElements[i].style["strokeDashoffset"] = 0;
}

function checkMousePosition(down) {
  for (i = 0; i < logoElements.length; i++) {
    if (down) logoElements[i].style["strokeDashoffset"] = logoElements[i].getTotalLength();
    else logoElements[i].style["strokeDashoffset"] = 0;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function mouseState(e) {
  checkMousePosition(true);
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function mouseState(e) {
  checkMousePosition(false);
});
```

And add eg `transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;` to `#first path`